# Self-Study Regimen

Tags: self-learning

What are the prerequisites to self study projective geometry and universal algebra?
The farthest I've gotten is undergraduate abstract algebra: Groups, Rings, Fields. Of course there is a lot left, but specifically what books should I read? I still have no experience in analysis, was considering Rudins book. For the algebra I was going to read Dummit and Foote. After I read these will I be ready for universal algebra and projective geometry?

Comment: Why not just start studying it and when you get stuck on something research that in particular?

Comment: In terms of specific knowledge, you have enough background to study universal algebra and projective geometry. Apart from that it's just a matter of having enough mathematical maturity, and that depends on you having studied enough math in general. There's a chapter on universal algebra in Jacobson's *Basic Algebra II*. For projective geometry, where to study it depends on your goals, but if what you want is an axiomatic approach, Artin's *Geometric Algebra* and Hartshorne's *Foundations of Projective Geometry* are both good. For a non-axiomatic approach, there's a good book in French by...

Comment: Samuel, but I don't know if it has an English translation.